# Test case in jasmine

Tags: javascript, postgresql, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am very new to Jasmine. In fact, I just started today and don't have prior knowledge writing JS unit test cases. But I want to complete one task - I have a set of data like (model,type,vehicle) etc. in CSV format and uploaded that data into PostgreSQL database. Now I want to write a test case in Jasmine to check whether the data has been uploaded in the database is same to the csv file or not. Can anyone, please, help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine is a unit testing framework which generally works on mocking data. It's not an ideal case to do the background APIs calls in unit tests.

The only way I can think of handling this case is, for each Jasmine unit test you have to first load the data from API/DB using the HTTP/WebSocket call, and wait for that to finish and then apply your test. Just like below

```
describe('postgres-sql data verification', () => {
    it('data verification async task', (done) => {
        someService.getData().then(() => {
            //do the expect checks here and then
            done()
        })
    })
})
```

Make sure the test are running over some browser instance for example - PhantomJS or Chrome.

Or else - Why not write some API test which can check your CSV and database data validation?